# JS does not work indirect execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this js code that works perfectly with double click, but when I try to incorporate it in another file it doesn't work. The code is supposed to display a POP up window on button click. The problem in the second case is that what should be displayed in pop window, displays directly in the browser and when clicking the button nothing happens. Does anyone has experience with this things?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( "#hello" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
                $( "#say_it" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#hello" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This page wants to say "Hello!"<br>
        Be nice and press the button.</p>
        <button id="say_it">Say "Hello!"</button>
        <div id="hello" title="Hello  World!"><p><font face="Georgia" size="4">
        Hey, world, I just said "Hello!"</font></p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share us your "incorporate" solution?

Comment: I mean: Suppose that this file is f1.html, when I try to call it by f2 (for example there is a link in f2.html), it doesn't work. But when I open it with double click it works.

Comment: I don'tb see your link

Answer (score 1):

is a library that simulates a popup with styles, 
so is a pop of the current window

internal popup with Jquery-ui

```
$('.some').dialog( "open" );
```

it's external popup

```
prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
```

another

```
alert('other popup');
```

and another

```
window.open('popup.html');
```

Comment: Thank you but could you please suggest what exactly to change in my code?

Comment: you need an internal or external popup?

Comment: I need to call this file from another one when I click a button. I want to display exactly this pop up window not a simple prompt text. Thank you.

Comment: from another 'js' file or other file 'html'?

Comment: It's a .php in fact. Does it make difference?

Comment: no :). You can not call from another tab or window, but if you can from a file in common for both